# How to speed up a video (make a time lapse) using gstreamer?

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing

I'm looking to take a video of say 1 minute in length, and speed it up so that it is only say 10 seconds long (x6). I don't want to just change the display rate, I'd like to actually drop 5 out of 6 frames in this example to reduce the size and the length of the video.

How can I achieve this using the gstreamer command line?

I've tried using the `videorate` filter:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 \
! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate 
! video/x-raw,framerate=180/1 ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

but no matter what parameters I pass, although frames are dropped, the length of the video stays the same.

Comment: since you're asking about the gstreamer command line, not programmatic use, perhaps you should take this to https://superuser.com/ -- if this were ffmpeg, I'd suggest reassigning PTSes according to your formula. learn about Presentation TImestamps (PTS)

Comment: The `videorate` element is not a way to do this - that is specifically for changing frame rate but keeping duration the same (by copying or duplicating frames). What you want is to send a "seek request" with rate=6. I am not sure this is possible with command line only, but would be very easy with a python script or something.

Comment: @nathaniel-bubis, I've (many times, see history) edited an answer for a simple command line solution. You may also get better support from https://discourse.gstreamer.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rate` parameter to videorate.

Here's your pipeline updated:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 \
! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! \
\
videorate rate=6 \
\
! video/x-raw,framerate=180/1 ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

I think you want to reduce the frame rate at the same time:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 \
! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! \
\
videorate rate=6 \
! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! \
\
x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

(I asked someone this question on the mailing list a few months back.  Thanks should really go to them!)

Comment: Thank you! this almost works - it speeds up the video, but the video retains the same 1 minute length, except that all the motion is packed into the first 10 seconds.

Comment: I see a duration of 10.83 using:`ffprobe` or `vlc` (though on my version of gstreamer, `gst-discoverer-1.0` seg-faults for some reason)

using this pipeline also gives 10.83 seconds:
`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="output.mp4" ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

Comment: I was using
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball num-buffers=1800 ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=in.mp4` to generate my input video

Comment: I've run your commands exactly, and yet the same issue occurs. Looking at `gst-discoverer-1.0 output.mp4`, one sees `duration: 0:01:00.000000000`

Comment: Very unexpected!  I've just rechecked with the same commands and get `Duration: 0:00:10.833333333` running gstreamer v1.20.3

Comment: P.S.  I forgot to say 'thanks' to @SeB for the quick and easy test video creation command!

Answer (score 1):

Create a 1 minute sample 320x240@30 video for testing with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=ball num-buffers=1800 ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=test_h264.mp4
```

This workaround involves a first command launching a pipeline decoding to I420 raw video and sending to stdout, and another gstreamer command  launching a pipeline reading raw video from stdin at 180 fps, then using videorate for dropping 5 frames out of 6 back to 30 fps, then encoding into H264 and put into mp4 container:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -q filesrc location=test_h264.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! fdsink \
| gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! videoparse format=i420 width=320 height=240 framerate=180 ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=240,framerate=180/1 ! videorate ! video/x-raw,format=I420,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! qtmux ! filesink location=testOut.mp4

# Check video details
gst-discoverer-1.0 -v testOut.mp4

# Check sizes:
ls -l test*.mp4

# Play it
gst-play-1.0 testOut.mp4
```